# Wysiwyg is not working in the group field wordpress codestar framwork

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, frameworks

I am trying to add one+ more item with Wysiwyg editor in group field with codestar framework metabox option,but it is not working . I tried to figure out solution,but i found that when i rename class of below hidden section, it hidden section get's appear and it works or editor function works correctly for this current item only. but also when i delete this hidden section with saving two or more item ....

**Hidden Section:**

```
echo '<div class="cs-group cs-group-'. $el_class .'-adding hidden">';
echo '<h4 class="cs-group-title">'. $acc_title .'</h4>';
echo '<div class="cs-group-content">';

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $field['sub']   = true;
    $unique         = $this->unique .'[_nonce]['. $this->field['id'] .']['. $last_id .']';
    $field_default  = ( isset( $field['default'] ) ) ? $field['default'] : '';
    echo cs_add_element( $field, $field_default, $unique );
}

echo '<div class="cs-element cs-text-right cs-remove">
        <a href="#" class="button cs-warning-primary cs-remove-group">'. 
            esc_html__( 'Remove', 'cs-framework' ) .'</a>
    </div>';

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

[image]

**Appeared Full Section:**

```
echo '<div class="cs-groups cs-group-'. $el_class .'-addings hiddens">';
echo '<h4 class="cs-group-title">'. $acc_title .'</h4>';
echo '<div class="cs-group-content">';

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $field['sub']   = true;
    $unique         = $this->unique .'[_nonce]['. $this->field['id'] .']['. $last_id .']';
    $field_default  = ( isset( $field['default'] ) ) ? $field['default'] : '';
    echo cs_add_element( $field, $field_default, $unique );
}

echo '<div class="cs-element cs-text-right cs-remove">
        <a href="#" class="button cs-warning-primary cs-remove-group">'. 
        esc_html__( 'Remove', 'cs-framework' ) .'</a>
    </div>';

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="cs-groups cs-accordion">';

if( ! empty( $this->value ) ) {
    foreach ( $this->value as $key => $value ) {
        $title = ( isset( $this->value[$key][$field_id] ) ) ? $this->value[$key][$field_id] : '';

        if('page_type_section' == $field_id) {
            $title = get_the_title($this->value[$key][$field_id]);
        }

        if ( is_array( $title ) && isset( $this->multilang ) ) {
            $lang  = cs_language_defaults();
            $title = $title[$lang['current']];
            $title = is_array( $title ) ? $title[0] : $title;
        }

        $field_title = ( ! empty( $search_id ) ) ? $acc_title : $field_title;

        echo '<div class="cs-group cs-group-'. $el_class .'-'. ( $key + 1 ) .'">';
        echo '<h4 class="cs-group-title">'. $field_title .': '. $title .'</h4>';
        echo '<div class="cs-group-content">';

        foreach ($fields as $field ) {
            $field['sub'] = true;
            $unique = $this->unique . '[' . $this->field['id'] . ']['.$key.']';
            $value  = ( isset( $field['id'] ) && isset( $this->value[$key][$field['id']] ) ) ? $this->value[$key][$field['id']] : '';
            echo cs_add_element( $field, $value, $unique );
        }

        echo '<div class="cs-element cs-text-right cs-remove">
                <a href="#" class="button cs-warning-primary cs-remove-group">'. 
                    esc_html__( 'Remove', 'cs-framework' ) .'</a>
            </div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';
echo '<a href="#" class="button button-primary cs-add-group">'. $this->field['button_title'] .'</a>';
echo wp_kses_post($this->element_after());
```

for the first item it works correctly, others not work. i have also inspected it, with inspect option. For the first item it is getting classes id or other thing, but then for the others are not getting or working.Any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.

Open cs-framework/fields/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.php

```
// Replace
wp_editor( $field_value, $field_id, $settings );

// to with
wp_editor( $field_value, $field_id.rand(0,20), $settings );
```